# Adding csv columns with cmd

Tags: csv, batch-file, cmd

I have 2 CSV files containing below data. I want to add the 3rd and 4th columns in a new CSV file using .cmd batch file. Is it possible to do it with .cmd batch file. If yes please help me with code.

File1.csv

```
SL,Name,Score,Result
1,Saquib,10,100
2,Tanzil,10,100
3,Hasib,10,100
4,Sharek,10,100
```

and

File2.csv

```
SL,Name,Score,Result
1,Saquib,20,200
2,Tanzil,30,300
3,Hasib,40,400
4,Sharek,50,500
```

The output should look like below.
Combine.csv

```
SL,Name,Score,Result
1,Saquib,30,300
2,Tanzil,40,400
3,Hasib,50,500
4,Sharek,60,600
```

I have a code that combines the 2 files but do not add the fields.

```
@echo off
ECHO Set working directory
pushd %~dp0`enter code here`
ECHO Deleting existing combined file
del combined.csv
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set cnt=1
for %%i in (*.csv) do (
  if !cnt!==1 (
    for /f "delims=" %%j in ('type "%%i"') do echo %%j >> combined.csv
  ) else if %%i NEQ combined.csv (
    for /f "skip=1 delims=" %%j in ('type "%%i"') do echo %%j >> combined.csv
  )
  set /a cnt+=1
```

Comment: ...to answer your question: Yes, it is possible.

Comment: haha thanks. Can you share any code?

Answer (score 0):

batch is not the scripting language for this type of operation, it would be faster and easier to use a language like powershell.

example assuming the first two columns of the two files are identical

```
$table1 = import-csv file1.csv
$table2 = import-csv file2.csv

# convert Score Result columns to type int
$table1 |% { $_.Score = [int]$_.Score; $_.Result = [int]$_.Result }
$table2 |% { $_.Score = [int]$_.Score; $_.Result = [int]$_.Result }

# add score and result for each row respectively
for ($i=0;$i -lt $table1.count;$i++) {
    $table1[$i].Score  += $table2[$i].Score
    $table1[$i].Result += $table2[$i].Result
}

# export
$table1 | export-csv output.txt
```

or, for example, using hashtables if first columns are not identical

```
$table1=import-csv file1.csv
$htable=@{}

foreach($r in $table1) {
    $r.Score = [int]$r.Score;
    $r.Result = [int]$r.Result;
    $htable[$r.SL] = $r;
}

$table2=import-csv file2.csv
foreach($r in $table2) { 
    $r.Score = [int]$r.Score + $htable[$r.SL].Score;
    $r.Result = [int]$r.Result + $htable[$r.SL].Result;
    $htable[$r.SL] = $r;
}

$htable.Values | export-csv output.txt
```

Comment: thanks a lot but does it work with older windows like 7?